# Bootstrap tabs not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

My bootstrap tabs are not working properly. I am not sure why. I have imported `jquery.js` in my files but still no use. Here is the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab01" data-toggle="tab">Post Autoliker</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab02" data-toggle="tab">Comment Autoliker</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab03" data-toggle="tab">Post Auto-commenter</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content tab">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab01">
            <h4>Post Autoliker <small>this is for autoliking wall posts. Will work on posts, posts from pages, photos and videos. ;)</small></h4>
            <hr />
            <form action="<?php echo $self; ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="number" name="post-id" value="" placeholder="Facebook Post ID" class="form-control" required="required" />
                <br /><input type="submit" name="do-like-posts" value="Like the Post!" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab02">
        <h4>Comment Autoliker <small>this is for autoliking post comments. Will work on any post on any comments. ;)</small></h4>
        <hr />
        <form action="<?php echo $self; ?>" method="post" class="form-inline" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group" style="width:50%">
                <input type="number" name="post-id" value="" placeholder="Facebook Post ID" class="form-control" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="width:49%">
                <input type="number" name="comment-id" value="" placeholder="Facebook Comment ID" class="form-control" required="required" />
            </div>
            <p></p><input type="submit" name="do-like-comments" value="Like the Comment!" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab03">
        <h4>Post Auto-commenter <small>this is for auto-commenting on post. Will work on posts, photos, and videos. ;)</small></h4>
        <hr />
```

Could someone help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same problem before. Use your browser's debug tool (I personally prefer Chrome) and check if you load jquery or bootstrap.js twice.

Comment: Hmm, it says .jquery-1.10.2.min.map
/jquery
GET
404
Not Found
text/html
Other
714 B
440 B
322 ms
313 ms
313 ms10 ms

Comment: jQuery is required. I think you have to make sure jQuery is loaded before bootstrap.js (and both for only once).

Comment: Yes it's loaded first before bootstrap. But there's 2 bootstrap.css that is run in the code 1 is stylesheet, one is javascript.

Comment: I created a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/CzdKr/) using your code and it seems pretty fine. Maybe you can compare it with your page to check if there's anything different between each other.

Comment: I got it fixed now. I added some js scripts on the bottome of my page from the bootstrap. Thanks to everyone though.

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/3230829/sync I am facing same issue , can you please guide which files you used to fix this issue? Thanks in advance